# Deserialize malformed Json returning empty arrays

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, deserialization, malformed

Please, I use VB.NET Http Requests to read data from a webservice. It used to send data this way:

```
[
    {
      "id": 7532,
      "nome": "LABOR INC.",
      "isClient": false,
      "personality": {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "CORPORATION"
      },
      "registryNumbers": [
        {
          "id": 9378,
          "number": "20786790174"
        }
      ],
      "personality_id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 7537,
      "nome": "JOSE SILVA",
      "isClient": false,
      "personality": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "PERSON"
      },
      "gender": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "MALE"
      },
      "cityOfBirth": {
        "id": 355030,
        "value": "SAO PAULO"
      },
      "nationality": {
        "id": 85,
        "value": "BRAZILIAN"
      },
      "registryNumbers": [
        {
          "id": 9383,
          "number": "03217495388"
        }
      ],
      "personality_id": 1
    }
]
```

It was ok because unused fields (as "gender" and "cityOfBirth" for corporations) were omitted. Since some days, however, it started to send back these fields as empty arrays (`[]`), like this:

```
{
  "id": 7532,
  "nome": "LABOR INC.",
  "isClient": false,
  "personality": {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "CORPORATION"
  },
  "gender": [],
  "cityOfBirth": [],
  "nationality": [],
  "registryNumbers": [
    {
      "id": 9378,
      "number": "20786790174"
    }
  ],
  "personality_id": 2
}
```

And because of that it misfit the destiny properties in deserialization class, because these are not (and can't be) enumerations/arrays but single objects.

**My question**: is there some deserialization extension or attribute I can add to my classes in order to deserialize those (`[]`) as null/Nothing? Special thanks if it comes in VB.NET, but I'm able to read and adapt C# as well.

That is, I'd like to know how I could make my code halt when an array is "forced" into a property that expects single objects, and do the proper treatment at this point.

Comment: that's not "malformed json". it's perfectly valid. it's your structures that can't handle it. if there isn't something that can override the internal deserilizations, then decode to a temp structure, fiddle with that to do change the empty arrays to whatever you want, then feed that to your code.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcB. Do you mean `[]` is also the way null values are represented in JSON?

Comment: no. `[]` is an empty array. that's not null. a null in json (which is really just javascript) is the literal word `null`. if you can be 100% **SURE** that you'll never have `[]` appear anywhere else in the json, you could do a simple `[] -> null` string replacement on the json before decoding it.

Comment: Then it *is* malformed in the sense that those properties are to carry a single object, not an array. It may not be invalid JSON *syntax*, but is incoherent with the object model schema they use. That's what I meant with "malformed", sorry if it was a bad expression.

Comment: then maybe go look at what's generating the json. if it's outputting (for your purposes) "garbage", then it's better to fix what's generating the json, than try to clean up the "garbage". if this is a published change in the api, then you'll have to adjust your code.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately I can't do a whole sweeping replace because JSON expression is far more complex than I reproduced in question, and *there are* properties that do have an array type, where `[]`is a perfectly valid content. On the other hand, the software that "makes" this JSON is inside my organization, but in a level beyond my ability to request changes to it. I'd like to know how I could make my code halt when an array is "forced" into a property that expects single objects, and do the proper treatment at this point.

Comment: You might be able to parse some other value like that "CORPORATION" value and then conditionally deserialize to a different type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried and solved the problem with a custom converter:

```
Public Class BogusArrayJsonConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter
    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return GetType(MyRecord).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
    End Function
    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        If reader.TokenType = JsonToken.StartArray Then
            Return serializer.Deserialize(Of MyRecord())(reader).SingleOrDefault
        Else
            Return serializer.Deserialize(Of MyRecord)(reader)
        End If
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks to all who tried to help me.